# Enable to install Linux Ultimate Edition (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, operating-systems, bootable-media

After I deleted `Linux` partition from `Windows 7`, I wanted to install a new version [Linux Ultimate Edition 3.8](http://ultimateedition.info/) which is based on `Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail`. So I made a `bootable usb`, but when I boot and select install the installation begins but doesn't continue normally (The screen is turned off) and nothing happens after that. I don't know where is the problem situated, I tried it on another PC and it works fine (I was able to install it).

Any suggections ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the installer may be entering a video mode unsupported by your display. Is there a "safe mode" installer, or a way you can select the resolution of the installer?

Comment: May be ! I don't know. I've already installed an old version of it, I think the 3.6 version and I'd not encountered that problem. And no, I don't think there is a way to fix the resolution of the installer. Is there another solution to fix that ? Thanks